# .cs page not showing proper string

Tags: c#, string, unicode

I got an application to work on, when I was looking into it, I found that there are N number of places where string is not showing properly and it got changed as below. I asked to my client he is saying it is looking okay at his place. As it is many places I can not go to one one screen to change.

Can someone please help and let me know how can again change it to original string.
I am using Visual Studio 2015.

```
lblComment.Text = "´Ë¹¦ÄÜ½öÓÃÓÚµ±MES¹¤µ¥ÎÞ·¨È·ÈÏÊ±£¬³¢ÊÔÈ¥ÐÞ¸´ÎÊÌâ¡£Èç¹ûÊÔ¹ýÖ®ºó»¹ÊÇ²»ÄÜÈ·ÈÏ£¬¿ÉÄÜÐèÒª²é¿´SAPµÄÉèÖÃ£¬¿ÉÄÜÊýÁ¿»òÕßÆäËûµÄÉèÖÃÓÐÎÊÌâ¡£";

lblErrorMsg.Text = "ÇëÊäÈë¹¤µ¥ºÅ";
```

Comment: Do you have some sort of version control system that screws up the data transported? Probably nothing we can do here.

Comment: That sounds like something changed the code-page of the source file - for example, between unicode and ASCII. Are you sure this isn't a bug in whatever code management / repo tools you're using? It could also be that it is using ANSI code-pages, and you and the other person simply have different ANSI settings (in which case, the ideal solution is for whoever created the file to ensure that it is saved with an explicit encoding, presumably UTF-8)

Comment: @MarcGravell this is not a bug, May be user have different ANSI setting and saving the file explicitly then what would be the solution now so change it again to normal string?

Comment: Looks fine to me - if you view it in ANSI simplified Chinese (GB2312) encoding. I think @MarcGravell is spot on with this. This is a simple codepage conversion probably caused by some source control

Comment: @Rocky there's no such thing as a "normal string" here - what you need to do is get the right encoding; in "current" VS, you would use: File -> Open->File... then select the file, then click the down arrow on the "Open" button, and change it to "Open With...", then choose "CSharp Editor with Encoding", and then tell it what encoding it was saved with. Even better: tell everyone involved in the project to **always** use UTF-8, and to never use any editor that can't talk UTF-8

Comment: Not sure if it helps in this case, but you could also try to change the system locale of your Windows.